# Queue of operations

Tags: c++, queue, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I'm creating a class for configuration file handling. The way I want it to work is:

There's a queue that retains all the operations (insert data, erase data...), then, the method `Commit` will apply all those changes.

My prototypes looks like that (all the settings on the file are stored into a STL map):

```
bool Insert(std::string const& key, std::string const& value);
bool Erase(std::string const& key);
```

So, I've tried to create an STL queue of pointer to functions, but the functions don't have the same number of arguments, and I don't know what to do...

Comment: Since your functions don't have the same number of arguments, how were you planning on calling them?

Comment: That's the point... so, do you mind other workarounds to my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an Operation base class and then derive it twice to make Insert and Erase classes. You could then store pointers to the Operation class.

```
class Settings
{
public:
    bool Insert(std::string const& key, std::string const& value)
    {
        m_operations.push_back(new Insert(key, value));
        return true; //?      
    }

    bool Erase(std::string const& key)
    {
        m_operations.push_back(new Erase(key));
        return true; //?
    }

    bool Commit()
    {
        // You know what to do by now right ?
    }

private:
    class Operation
    {
    public:
        virtual void Execute() = 0
    }

    class Insert : public Operation
    {
    public:
        Insert(std::string const& key, std::string const& value) : 
            m_key(key), m_value(value) {}

        void Execute() {...}
    private:
        std::string m_key;
        std::string m_value;
    }

    class Erase : public Operation
    {
    public:
        Erase(std::string const& key) : m_key(key) {}

        void Execute() {...}
    private:
        std::string m_key;
    }

    std::queue<Operation*> m_operations;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> m_settings;
}
```

Then you either make your operation classes friend of the settings class or you pass a ref to the map the operation should by applied on.

Comment: I think it's just a typo but you wrote `Insert` instead of `Erase`. Thank you for your answer!